# I think JS is giving me Unicode when all I want is ASCII

Tags: javascript, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to take a character and increment or decrement it. I'm attempting to use `String.fromCharCode` to accomplish this. While the following works in a console

```
'Na' + String.fromCharCode(78 + n) // n is 2 in this example, can even hard-code it
```

seems to work properly and gives me `NaP`, something else in my code is giving me `Na̎` instead.

Here's the code block that is being executed

```
if (ifTypes(a, b, 'integer', 'NaN')) { // disregard this, inside code IS executing
    console.log("a: " + JSON.stringify(a) + "   b: " + JSON.stringify(b));
    var n = a[1] === 'NaN' ? b[0] : a[0];
    var output = 'Na' + String.fromCharCode(78 + n);
    console.log("output: " + output);
    return output;
}
```

From the console for verification:

```
a: [null,"NaN"]   b: ["2","integer"]
output: Na̎ // <-- SO's code highlighter is messing that up
```

And yes, if anyone recognizes what I'm doing, I am [implementing the interpreter from xkcd's 1537](https://github.com/agweber/1537). If you want to see this code in action and maybe try to read through my console output, I've got it [online here](http://agweber.net/1537-test). Just click in the lighter bar and press enter, it's just simulating a terminal.

I suspect the problem is some strange ascii/unicode toggle. I've tried putting the `'Na'` inside the `String.fromCharCode` but it gives the similar results. Though `a` should be `[NaN, "NaN"]`, I don't think that's the issue. I do need to track down that bug too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're adding `"2"` and `78`, instead of `2` and `78`.

```js
function print(s) {
  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += "<pre>" + s + "</pre>";
}

var a = [null, "NaN"];
var b = ["2", "integer"];

var n = a[1] === 'NaN' ? b[0] : a[0];
var output = 'Na' + String.fromCharCode(78 + n);
print("output 1: " + output);

output = 'Na' + String.fromCharCode(78 + (typeof n == "number" ? n : parseInt(n, 10)));
print("output 2: " + output);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: How did I not see this before. I've run into this same issue throughout this little mini-project a number of times.

Comment: @agweber I think it happens to all of us: you just cannot understand why would it not work for some time, then the aha-moment occurs, and now you cannot understand why it was so hard to find this little simple bug.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is a string, not an integer, so the addition isn't doing what you expect.

Change

```
var output = 'Na' + String.fromCharCode(78 + n);
```

to

```
var output = 'Na' + String.fromCharCode(78 + parseInt(n));
```